# Email non-empty cells in tabular format

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, email

I'm trying to trigger an email to send all data on a sheet in columns B:F. I've found [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/sending_emails) quite helpful but can't quite get my head round it.

```
/**
 * Sends emails with data from the current spreadsheet.
 */
function email() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");

  var startRow = 1; // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 2; // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B3
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 2, numRows, 6);
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = "abc@cba.com"; // First column
    var message = row[1]; // Second column
    var subject = 'Jobs in Next 5 Days';
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  }
}
```

What would I need to change that in order to send all non-blank data in B:F on Sheets in one email but keeping the tabular spreadsheet format?

Answer (score 0):

You could send emails using plain text, HTML or both.

- If you decide to use plain text, then you could use a tab character by using `\t` as the column separator.
- If you decide to use HTML, then you could use the table tags like

  ```
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Columna A</th>
      <th>Column B</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Value A</td>
      <td>Value B</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  ```

Be aware that the body (plain text) an htmlBody (HTML) arguments should be strings

For further details checkout:

- [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10483498/1595451) to [Use spreadsheet data to populate html table in email](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10476064/1595451)
- [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36581650/1595451) to [Use MailApp to send formatted data from spreadsheet in htmlBody](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36577984/1595451)